# Is there a way to write an if statement to catch an input and automatically enter a string?

Tags: python, pexpect

```
import pexpect
from BODMASCalculator import math

Math = pexpect.spawn(math('aaaa'))
Math.expect("error incorrect Format try again?(y/n)", 'n')
Math.sendline('n')
```

i have been trying to use pexpect to automatically enter 'n' when this input is returned but im having no luck so far

any help greatly appreciated

Comment: It is unclear what are you willing to do.

Comment: basically i want to write a function to automatically input 'n' when it receives the prompt to fill the input without manually having to type in 'n'

Answer (score 0):

Try as follow (just on Windows platforms):

```
import msvcrt
while True:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        key_stroke = msvcrt.getch()
        if key_stroke == b'n':
            value = input("Please enter a string:\n")
            print(f'You entered {value}')
```